# Laravel - Stop sending emails on runtime

Tags: php, laravel, email

In my Laravel 7.5 app I send an email whenever a record is created (triggered via model events). The emails are sent using `mailgun` driver on production.

However, there is an import functionality, and when an import is used, I don't want to send thousands of emails. What is the best way to pause or disable Laravel email on runtime just for the execution of current request/script?

I have tried a few things.

- Setting mail driver to `log` or `array`

```
config(['mail.driver' => 'log'])
```

Worked fine on local/dev (using smtp driver), but on production it didn't stop emails.

- Listening to `MessageSending` event and returning `false` to prevent the email. Again, worked fine on local using `smtp` driver but did not stop emails on production using `mailgun` driver.

Currently I call `Mail::fake()` to swap the Mail facade with the fake. Seems to work fine, but feels very hacky and potentially will not work with different drivers and/or queued messages.

Is there a better, cleaner way to temporarily and globally pause email sending? I would not want to stop the events from dispatching as they do other processing apart from emails as well.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe config cached on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this idea, but you can try to flash a variable to your session before the import logic for example:

```
session()->flash('import_disable_email',true);

// import logic here
```

And in your model event handling check if the session key exists like so:

```
if(!session('import_disable_email')){ // or !== null
  // send email logic here
}
```

Of course if you want to keep your session variables clean after the save logic you can delete that entry with:

```
// import logic here

session()->forget('import_disable_email');
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about that (a session or just a flag for the single script), but I am looking (if possible) for a cleaner solution where I don't have to manually edit every individual even listener :/

Comment: Hmm.. The only other thing i can think off is to set a [universal to](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#mail-and-local-development) by calling `config([ 'mail.to' => $arrWithAddressAndName ])` I wouldn't say this is a clean solution either though since email is still triggered

Answer (score 0):

When issuing a mass update or delete via Eloquent, the `saved`, `updated`, `deleting`, and `deleted` model events will not be fired for the affected models.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events

Comment: Correct, however, I create models one-by-one and I do need the `saved` and other events fired as they do perform other actions that are needed for the import.